# Loading a Text font - Bold and Italic issue

Tags: rendering, text-object

I want to use the "Avenir Next" font for a Text object. More specifically I want to use the Ultra Light ("Ultralätt" in Swedish) version of the font. As you can see on the first screenshot, Ultra Light is an alternative built right into the font (among others). The problem is that when I load the Avenir Next font into Blender, only the Bold version of the font loads. Since a lot of fonts has things like Normal, Italic and Bold versions of the font stored in the same font file I'm wondering how I can load my preferred version of the font since Blender seems to only load in one version of it?

[image]

[image]

[image]